# iOS How can I set transparent in Container viewcontroller

Tags: ios, containers, transparent

I had embed UIPageViewController in the Root Viewcontroller.

Like below photo .

[image]

But I want to set First,second View controller background transparent, and it's still can show view controller text 1 and 2.

So It will show Root background color(black) and the root view controller can swipe though the uipageviewcontroller.

My pageviewcontroller part code below:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.delegate = self;
self.dataSource = self;
pageControl = [UIPageControl appearance];
pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

UIViewController *p1 = [self.storyboard
                        instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Intro1ID"];


UIViewController *p2 = [self.storyboard
                        instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Intro2ID"];

myViewControllers = @[p1,p2];

[self setViewControllers:@[p1]
               direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                animated:NO completion:nil];

self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
self.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
```

}

Have anyone can teach me how to set the containerview background color transparent and can show 1 , 2 text?
(It is sample code, so that just 1, 2 text)

thank you very much.

Comment: `[[p1 view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];`? And the same for `p2`?

Comment: oh oh oh!! you are right, @Larme. Can you type in  answer question. I will give you correct answer. thank you:P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
[[p1 view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[[p2 view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

The issue is that the background view of your `UIViewController` was not transparent.